# parsing data for multiple cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

if the following example in a cell:

Employee Name: **xxxxxx xxxxxxxx**
Department: **xxxxx:xxxxxxx**
Title: **xxxx xxxx xxxx**
Manager: **xxxx xxxxx**
Start Date: **8/10/2015**
Location: **Seattle**

can anyone help me parse these values(bold) out into multiple cells? Thanks for looking!

PS I know nothing about VBA. Is that my best bet? I understand boolean as I have a little background in Python.

Comment: Show your effort! Hint: the `MID` and `FIND` functions can help.

Answer (score 0):

Find and replace your static values of "Employee Name", "Department", "Title", etc. one at a time. They should be replaced with nothing. To make the data cleaner, you can also replace instances of " : " with just ":". You can also replace ": " with nothing to drop the first colon (which you won't need). Your example should now look like the following:

xxxxxx xxxxxxxx:xxxxx:xxxxxxx:xxxx xxxx xxxx:xxxx xxxxx:8/10/2015:Seattle

You can now perform a "Text to Columns" operation:

- Select the "Data" tab in the ribbon
- Select "Text to Columns"
- Change the radio button to "Delimited"
- Click "Next"
- In the "Other" field, input a colon ":"
- Click "Next"
- Select your "MDY" date field
- Select "Date" as the "Column Data Format"
- Click "Finish"

The colon in the middle of Department causes a problem. If you need department to be in a single field, then you can insert a new column D. You can concatenate columns B and C with the following:

`=B1 & C1`

- Put that formula into cell D1
- Double-click on the fill handle
- Right-click on Column D
- Select Copy
- Right-Click on D1
- Select Paste Special
- Choose Values
- Click OK
- Delete Columns B and C

If you need this as a VBA function that you can quickly repeat, then just record it.